# How do I count the number of buckets that match a condition in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a collection of documents describing the scores of users. The same user will have multiple scores.

My data is structured like so:

```
[
  { "user_id" : 3, "score" : 10 },
  { "user_id" : 1, "score" : 20 },
  { "user_id" : 2, "score" : 60 },
  { "user_id" : 1, "score" : 10 },
  ...
]
```

I am trying to determine each user's max score. The elastic search query that I am using looks like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id",
        "size": 9999
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_score": {
          "max": {
            "field": "score"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response looks like this:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "users": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "1",
          "doc_count": 10,
          "max_score": {
            "value": 10
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "2",
          "doc_count": 10,
          "max_score": {
            "value": 20
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I find the number of buckets where `max_score > 20`, `max_score > 50`, and `max_score > 100`?

Is there any way to make the response look like below?

```
  "aggregations": {
    "users": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "1",
          "doc_count": 10,
          "max_score": {
            "value": 10
          }
        },
        ...
      ],
      "scoresGreaterThan20": {
         "value": 10
      },
      "scoresGreaterThan50": {
         "value": 5
      },
      "scoresGreaterThan100": {
         "value": 2
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your use case by repeating the same terms and max aggregation along with [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html), for different conditions you need. Adding a working example -

**Index Data:**

```
  { "user_id" : 3, "score" : 10 }
  { "user_id" : 1, "score" : 20 }
  { "user_id" : 2, "score" : 60 }
  { "user_id" : 1, "score" : 10 }
```

**Search Query:**

**You can use [stats bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-stats-bucket-aggregation.html) to get the count of buckets after performing the bucket selector aggregation.**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "user_gt20": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id",
        "size": 9999
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_score": {
          "max": {
            "field": "score"
          }
        },
        "scoresGreaterThan20": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "values": "max_score"
            },
            "script": "params.values > 20"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "user_gt20_count": {
      "stats_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "user_gt20._count"
      }
    },
    "user_gt50": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id",
        "size": 9999
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_score": {
          "max": {
            "field": "score"
          }
        },
        "scoresGreaterThan50": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "values": "max_score"
            },
            "script": "params.values > 50"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "user_gt50_count": {
      "stats_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "user_gt50._count"
      }
    },
    "user_gt100": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id",
        "size": 9999
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_score": {
          "max": {
            "field": "score"
          }
        },
        "scoresGreaterThan100": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "values": "max_score"
            },
            "script": "params.values > 100"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "user_gt100_count": {
      "stats_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "user_gt100._count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "aggregations": {
    "user_gt100": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": []
    },
    "user_gt20": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 2,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "max_score": {
            "value": 60.0
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "user_gt50": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 2,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "max_score": {
            "value": 60.0
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "user_gt20_count": {
      "count": 1,            // note this
      "min": 1.0,
      "max": 1.0,
      "avg": 1.0,
      "sum": 1.0
    },
    "user_gt50_count": {
      "count": 1,             // note this
      "min": 1.0,
      "max": 1.0,
      "avg": 1.0,
      "sum": 1.0
    },
    "user_gt100_count": {
      "count": 0,             // note this
      "min": null,
      "max": null,
      "avg": null,
      "sum": 0.0
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. After using the bucket selector, is there any way I can get the count of the number buckets? Just to figure out how many users scored greater than x.

Comment: @EricWeiler yes you can get the count of buckets using stats bucket aggregation, please go through the updated search query and result and let me know if this resolves your issue ?